# Is it possible to draw $6$ circles of equal radius each passing through the centres of exactly three others?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Is it possible to draw $6$ circles of equal radius each passing through the centres of exactly three others?

The problem seems to be a direct application of pigeonhole principle but how to use it? May I get a hint?

Here's my take on the Problem : Consider the nodes of the graph as the centres of the circle and the edges as the connection between two circles. Then there will be 9 such edges. Assume that the radius of each circle is $1$ unit. So, how do we ensure that each edge is indeed $\leq 1$ unit?

Comment: I think the problem is not proving that $\leq 1$ but that your graph indeed represents what you want.  That it can be drawn and that each circle goes through no more than 3 center points.

Comment: @EnjoysMath the question asks us to show if it's possible or not to draw such a configuration. For the possibility, the only way is to show that the edges are $\leq 1$.

Comment: But the edges have to *equal* $r = 1$ don't they.  I mean you don't want to write the $\lt$ part.

Comment: @EnjoysMath No. You've to show that the edges are $\leq 1$

Comment: I think that you say the vertices are the circles, and two are adjacent if they pass through each others' centers.  There are only two $3$-regular graphs of order $6$.  One is $K_{3,3}$ which is clearly impossible.  I can't decide about the other.

Comment: If $C$ passes through $D$'s center then by definition the distance between the center points is $1$.

Comment: It says that the circle will pass through the centres. The question doesn't say that the circumference will pass through. Any part of the circle might be passing

Comment: @Mathbg The circle is the curve.  The region bounded by a circle is a disk.

Comment: @saulspatz I'm at the same stage - the other one looks like a triangular prism but I can't see a good reason why it should or shouldn't work

Comment: @B.Mehta All I see is the $3$-cycle which means that $3$ of the centers have to be at the vertices of an equilateral triangle, but I haven't been able to turn that to account.  Wait!  There are two $3$-cycles aren't there?

Comment: So, have we decided on circle vs disk yet?

Comment: @saulspatz That was the last push I needed! Posted an answer, which I'm fairly sure is correct.

Comment: @B.Mehta Yes it is.  I'm so bad at geometry -- even after I realized there were two equilateral triangles, I didn't see the answer.  I guess we've proved that the configuration is unique, haven't we?

Comment: The 'translation' I mention can happen in (almost) any direction, but other than that it is unique! I wasn't expecting this to be possible at all - I was searching for some forbidden subgraph instead!

Comment: Yes, I was trying to prove it impossible too.  When you posted your answer, the first thing I did was look for a mistake, then I realized there wasn't one.

Answer (score 8):

Yes!
Draw an equilateral triangle with side length $r$. Then translate the triangle by $r$.

[image]

Note: This answer uses the conventional definition of a "circle" to mean the set of points of a fixed distance away from a given point.

Comment: Is that a 2D plane?

Comment: Yes, it's entirely 2d.

Comment: @B.Mehta not enough algebra.  J/k wasn't me, I upvoted, but maybe that was premature?

Comment: @EnjoysMath Not enough algebra?  It's a geometry problem.

Comment: @saulspatz I said J/k.  But some geometry problems are nicely resolved algebraically, for instance construction problems like squaring the circle.

Comment: in my opinion asking about downvotes is futile.

Comment: @Mathbg I love it when you say thrice.  :D

Comment: Ah - and we're back to the circle vs disk issue

Comment: @Mathbg:  your figure seems to me to demonstrate the solution is correct.  Each point has three others at distance $r$, so if you draw a circle of radius $r$ around each point it goes through the center of three others.

Comment: @EnjoysMath I didn't understand what "J/k" meant.  I've googled it though, and now I see.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sir, there are four red points which are bounded. That explicitly explains the incorrectness not the solution as there should be exactly three points bounded.

Comment: @Mathbg:  I hadn't read the whole comment chain to your question showing your confusion between circle and disk.  The answer is correct for circles.  Point A is not on the unit circle with center E.

Comment: @RossMillikan Then you can regard it as a disc. By "circle", it's often meant to be the area of the circle and not just the circumference. But anyway, please consider it as a disc to remove the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A **cubic** (degree 3 for every vertex) graph with **6 vertices** and **unit distance edges** will probably suffice.

In general, a **unit distance graph** with $n$ vertices and edges with degree $k$ will probably satisfy your problem.

B. Mehta gives one such graph, the *prism graph* $Y_3$. Though $K_{3,3}$ has 6 vertices and is cubic,  it is not a unit distance graph in the plane or 3 dimensions.

Here is the Petersen graph with 10 vertices as a unit distance graph:

[image]

Here is the cubic matchstick graph with 8 vertices, the smallest such graph that is also planar:

[image]

There are many other examples.

Comment: It can be shown that there cannot be a copy of $K_{2,3}$ in a unit distance graph, so $K_{3,3}$ is not unit distance. In this way, the graph in my answer is unique, and the prism structure shown is unique up to the direction of translation.